# Preferable to vs. Better than

Tags: grammar

Staying at home is "preferable to" going out with someone you don't like.

Staying at home is "better than" going out with someone you don't like.

Do the two sentences mean exactly the same thing? If not, could you please explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say something is preferable is to say it is a better *choice*. This does not always mean it is better. For example, in the context of some vaccinations "old people are preferable to young people" may be true (if they are more likely to get sick when unvaccinated) while "old people are better than young people" may be false.

In your example the two sentences are almost the same, though there may be some reason I can't think of to prefer the worse alternative.